# How to copy constraint to other object and keep the drivers?

Tags: constraints, drivers

I add a constraint to an object, and in the parameter i attach drivers. Now when i copy/paste this constraint to other objects, all the drivers are gone. The drivers are converted automatically into static value. Is there any way i can copy/paste constraint and still have the drivers?

Thanks

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/240203/rigging-copy-constraints-in-version-2-80-and-above