# Rigging - Copy Constraints in Version 2.80 and above

Tags: rigging, interface, add-on, constraints

Many changes have been made since 2.80 came out.  How do I copy constraints from one bone to another in versions 2.80 and above. using a keyboard shortcut as in 2.79 and below?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy constraints from one bone to another?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41709/how-to-copy-constraints-from-one-bone-to-another)   _`Pose > Constraints > Copy Constraints to Selected Bones`_

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a replacement for the CTRL-C shortcut for copying bone constraints.  (It's used by a lot of tutorials.) They just need to enable the add-on.

Comment: Since the accepted answer is not in the question listed as a duplicate, I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2.8x and 2.9x you need to first enable a built-in addon, *Interface: Copy Attributes Menus* in preferences:

[image: Enabling copy attributes menu]

Once that's done, to copy constraints:

- Enter pose mode
- Select all of the bones you want to copy the constraint *to*
- Add the bone you want to copy the constraint *from* to the selection
- Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to bring up this menus:

[image: Copy Attributes menu with copy constraints selected]

- Select *Copy Selected Constraints*  When you do a menu will pop up showing all of the constrains on the source bone:

[image: Copy Constraints selection menu]

- Select the constraints you want to copy and click OK